# DataTables: json is undefined in initComplete()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

*jquery.dataTables.min.js: DataTables 1.10.12*

I need to get access to a table rows after data has been loaded ([deferred](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html)). And I can't because `json` is `undefined` for me inside [initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) function. Despite my table is loaded and I see all data. Also, there is `settings` data inside the function.

Why is that? Did I forget some option?

My code:

```
var data_table = task_submit_table.DataTable({
    "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
      console.log(json);
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "deferRender": true,
    "deferLoading": 0,
    "ordering": true,
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "ajax": {
      "url": "get_task_list/",
      "type": "POST",
      "dataType": "json"
    },
    "columns": [
      {"title": "Id", "data": "id"},
      {"title": "Date", "data": "date"},
      {"title": "Project Id", "data": "project_id"},
      {"title": "Project Name", "data": "project_name"},
      {"title": "project", "data": "biobank_project"},
      {"title": "#Hashes", "data": "nhashes"},
      {"title": "#Success", "data": "nsuccess"},
      {"title": "#Fail", "data": "nfail"},
      {"title": "Status", "data": "status"},
      {"title": "Report", "data": null},
      {"title": "", "data": null},
      {"title": "", "data": null}
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
      {
        "targets": [0],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": true
      },
      {
        "targets": [2],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": true
      },
      {
        "targets": -3,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": "<form id='tool-export' method='post' action='export/'>"+
          "<a href='#' id='export' class='btn btn-default export-link'>export</a></form>"
      },
      {
        "targets": -2,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": "<a href='#' id='task-delete' class='btn btn-default task-delete-link'"+
          "data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm_modal'>delete</a>"
      },
      {
        "targets": -1,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": "<a href='#' id='task-restart' class='btn btn-default task-restart-link'"+
          "data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm_modal'>restart</a>"
      }
    ],
    "dom": "<\"dt-btn-floatLeft\"l><\"dt-btn-floatRight\"B><\"dt-btn-clear\">rtip",
    "buttons": [
      {
        "title": "Refresh",
        "text": "Refresh",
        "action": function () {
          data_table.draw();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  data_table.draw();
```

In the frontend the table looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Try change `"initComplete"` to `"fnInitComplete"`

Comment: No success. There is settings data but json is still undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows in the deferred DataTables can be accessed via the [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) function. See the full response here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40659721/2393924

Answer (score 0):

You probably will want to use the drawCallback function which will execute everytime your table is fully drawn.

So it would look like this:

```
"drawCallback": function( settings ) {
    // You use this API object to get the data from the displayed data set.
    var api = this.api();
}
```

This drawCallback will execute every time the grid is redrawn so on:  sorting, filtering, paging, ajax.reload(), etc.  Where as the initComplete function I believe only fires once.  https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback